# Remove directory structure, but keep directory contents

Tags: linux, bash, directory

I meant to run this code inside a specific directory within my home directory, but accidentally ran it in my home directory itself:

```
i=0; for f in *; do d=dir_$(printf %03d $((i/8+1))); mkdir -p $d; mv "$f" $d; let i++; done
```

Now all my files and directories have been grouped into separate directories. I need to remove this action, and restore my original organization. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using shell expansion:

```
mv dir_*/* .
```

should move the content of all dir_ subdirectories back into the current one. For "hidden" files, if necessary, move `dir_*/.*`.